# Question about grub. Want to install Ubuntu 20.04 on 2nd hard drive, 1st hard drive already has dual boot win10 and Ubuntu

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, grubrescue

So doing some research here, nothing *quite* covers what I'm asking as far as I can tell, so please bear with me.

I already have a dual boot win10/Ubuntu 20.04 system running just fine (dev/sda). Custom computer, yada yada. I just bought a SSD and installed it, wanting to run Ubuntu on its own on the new SSD (dev/sdb). I loaded the live USB, installed as I normally would (also have dual boot on a surface), but after installation when trying to run off the SSD (dev/sdb), it goes into grub recovery. The only thing I can think of that I may have screwed up is pointing the bootloader to the wrong spot when installing, as I've only ever done dual boot on the same drive. When installing, I pointed it to the *new* drive (dev/sdb), should I have pointed it to the old drive (dev/sda) that already has a working installation? I've already wiped the install and formatted to unallocated in frustration last night and plan to start the install over once home from work.

Comment: UEFI or BIOS installs. Typically new install overwrites boot loader on older install & adds old install to grub menu. Selection of sdb only works with BIOS install. UEFI install always defaults to first drive, usually sda. DO NOT run any fix from Boot-Repair. Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the Boot-info summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed.
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Answer (score 0):

I apologize for taking so long to respond. UEFI. I was trying to get ahead of myself and do something I shouldn't based on my experience. Ended up just using the installer default options when installing to SSD (dev/sdb). I had originally chosen "something else" option, but must have messed up partitioning when trying to set up separate /, /home and swap partitions and/or pointed boot loader to the wrong drive? Anyways, apologies, this question can be locked if necessary. Thank you!