# How to Upgrade Ubuntu hard drive on dual boot, dual drive system

Tags: dual-boot, upgrade, hard-drive

I have a dual boot system.  Win10 and Ubuntu boot off separate drives.
I want to upgrade the Ubuntu hard drive.  It is too small.
I found the question/answer here:  [how-to-replace-my-disk-without-having-to-rebuild-my-ubuntu-install](https://askubuntu.com/questions/78076/how-to-replace-my-disk-without-having-to-rebuild-my-ubuntu-install) but this question only deals with a Ubuntu-only system.    The answer given was `sudo dd if=/dev/sda of=/dev/sdb`   The [Q/A here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1305910/question-about-grub-want-to-install-ubuntu-20-04-on-2nd-hard-drive-1st-hard-dr) is also different.

My question is different.   The answer to my question might be the same but I want to minimise the risk of messing up either the Win10 or Ubuntu installation. Reading through the different posts indicates failure is an option.

Comment: Using dd is for same size to same size. And some after the fact resizing may be difficult. Also you cannot have both drives plugged in unless you manually change UUIDs in one or the other. If a full install, I would just do a new install to new drive. Is system UEFI or BIOS. You must install in same mode. And then restore your data from your regular backup. That proves backup is complete or if something missing, you have old drive to add to backup & new install. You can always disconnect Windows drive. So it will not get modified, but you may need to restore the UEFI entry in UEFI.

Comment: Failure is always an option when modifying, adding, removing, or upgrading an OS.  If you need to simultaneously migrate to a new release and put the OS on a different hard drive, you should reinstall.

Comment: It has now been years since I setup my dual boot system. I have forgotten the details. It appears that I need to backup all of my data, then start with a bare disk for a fresh new Ubuntu install.  I will need to do some research because the details have probably changed since I last did this.